# Got "Resource could not be discovered.'' while asking for outlook calendar events

Tags: python, azure, outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch Outlook calendar events in Python scripts using API provided by Microsoft Graph.

I have created an Azure account using my personal Outlook account (example@outlook.com), after that I activated the account using student identity.

Then I have created an application following the instructions. In order to get access to my calendar via API, first I had to get a token. I followed the document and used  POST as below to get a token.
[image: POST to get token]
Here `username` is the admin username in my Azure application. Since my Outlook account is example@outlook.com, `username` here is admin@exampleoutlookcom.onmicrosoft.com

After getting my token, I called the Microsoft Graph API to get my calendar events:
[image]

But unfortunately, I just got this ERROR :
[image]

I am sure that the function to get events `get_calendar_events` is right.

I have searched the offical document for authentificating process, but almost all of them require manual click (Redirect to micorsoft login page to authentificate). I just want to write a simple python script to get my calendar events and print it in console, I don't need any web page to display.

Any suggestion will be helpful.Thanks very much

Comment: pls make sure your access token can be used for calling graph api successfully first.

Comment: How to? Could you please describe it in detail? Thanks a lot

Comment: Just like this example, send http request, but you also need to add Authorization as the http header. Using tools like postman. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUj2J.png

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with python code here. Here the issue is with Microsoft Personal Account. Even though you can use personal account with Azure AD, it remains a personal account only and there are some limitations around it.

In order to call /{user-id}/events,/calendar or /mailFolder to work the user must have mailbox on Exchange Online.

We are generally getting this {"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource could not be discovered."}} error for organizational users when license is not assigned to the users or mailbox is not configured for them.

In Microsoft personal Account user does not have a mailbox (which make sense with null value as below), so the call wouldn’t work.

[image]

It seems assigning license to a guest account (Microsoft personal account in this case) is not possible and hence the user account never gets access to the calendar service (part of o365 exchange online). due to which it cannot retrieve the calendar information of personal Outlook account. You may need to use a work or school account instead.

Thanks,
Shweta

Comment: So your idea is that my personal account cannot get access to graph API, But the official demo "Build Python Django apps with Microsoft Graph" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps) works for me. I can get my calendar events via this demo. Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of Flask or Django, so I have no idea about how it is implemented

Comment: Could you please check if any mailbox configured with your Personal Account or licence is assigned to the users?

Comment: I think I have granted all access to this account since its name starts with "admin", which means it can access all information in this application